# Add sound on hover to each item of menu without a pause

Tags: javascript, css

As I said I've created a menu which displays sound when I hover it. Code which I use is connected with a short pause before playing sound after hovering another item of the menu. How can I play it simultaneously, I mean, how can I remove the pause effect?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];
  $("#menu-glowne a")
    .mouseenter(function() {
      beepOne.pause();
      beepOne.play();
    });

});
```

```html
<audio id="beep-one" controls="controls" preload="auto">
  <source src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Click2-Sebastian-759472264.mp3"></source>
  <source src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Click2-Sebastian-759472264.wav"></source>
</audio>

<ul id="menu-glowne">
  <li><a href="#">One</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove the line that pauses it `beepOne.pause();`? Or do you mean you want something like overlapping sounds,eg new sound for each hover?

Comment: "*I've created a menu which displays sound when I hover it*" - please, either tell me that this site can be muted by the user, or tell me what the URL is so I can avoid ever going there. ...seriously, unless this is clearly announced on your site in advance of hovering that menu this is a UX nightmare.

Comment: Web audio api is best for this type of action . You will need to create an audio context and buffer source which will allow immediate audio response . Check here : https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html

Comment: I want to have overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Replace the pause with setTimeOut, or maybe jQuery .delay(). Example with 300ms timeout:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];
  $("#menu-glowne a")
    .mouseenter(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        beepOne.play();
      }, 300);
    });
});
```

I do not know if a new sound cancels out the previous one.

Also, as commented, playing sound unannounced is a bad user experience. You better have it disabled by default and ask the user, or let them enable it via a checkbox or something.